# How to see related commit for each entry in ls-tree output?

Tags: git

Basically, what I am asking is what git command (or chain of commands) does a service like gitlab or github use to show it's tree view?

Sorry, I'm not so good at English, it's hard for me to make a clear question.
Maybe it's more clear if I ask by doing.

Say, I run these commands:

```
 git init
 echo readme > readme
 git add readme 
 git commit -m 'initial commit'
 echo newfile > newfile
 git add newfile 
 git commit -m 'add newfile'
 echo 'readme line 2' >> readme 
 git add readme 
 git commit -m 'add line2 in readme'
 mkdir directory
 echo 'file within directory' > directory/file
 git add directory/file 
 git commit -m 'add file inside directory'
```

If I run `git ls-tree HEAD`, I'll get this:

```
mode   type hash                                     name
------ ---- ---------------------------------------- -----------
040000 tree 1886ff20e666d42f9c4684287bd87c45d4085d1e directory
100644 blob aa39060d7ee7daa8833a5ad2354c3f77d35cac71 newfile
100644 blob 8a19af2f451dc8ba3aa509914210c759a3f7edb7 readme
```

If I run `git log --pretty=oneline`, I'll get this:

```
commit hash                              commit message
---------------------------------------- -------------------------
e5791b809dbdc1c140124a822d812171bde9b1d1 add file inside directory
59a96b2dbab42d57ea74379ffb44b7ea97c75185 add line2 in readme
be90159c01a78190d32bc1b452da060d4ed61380 add newfile
2b0030b00a6b9ac56d63d3f1f2e46e7a3c796b4f initial commit
```

What I want is something to get something like this:

```
mode   type hash                                     name        commit message            commit hash                             
------ ---- ---------------------------------------- ----------- ------------------------- ----------------------------------------
040000 tree 1886ff20e666d42f9c4684287bd87c45d4085d1e directory   add file inside directory e5791b809dbdc1c140124a822d812171bde9b1d1
100644 blob aa39060d7ee7daa8833a5ad2354c3f77d35cac71 newfile     add newfile               be90159c01a78190d32bc1b452da060d4ed61380
100644 blob 8a19af2f451dc8ba3aa509914210c759a3f7edb7 readme      add line2 in readme       59a96b2dbab42d57ea74379ffb44b7ea97c75185
```

See? each tree's node show the related/last commit. Just like gitlab or github
does. Now, back to my question: what git command (or chain of commands) does a
service like gitlab or github use to show it's tree view?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? What sort of output are you looking for?

Comment: @larsks updated. I hope it clear enough :)

Answer (score 0):

OK, I got the solution:

```
# makes for loop works line by line
IFS=$'\n'

# assuming $COMMIT is a valid commit-ish
for line in $(git ls-tree $COMMIT)
do
    filename=$(echo $line | cut -f 2)
    node=$(echo $line | cut -f 1)
    commit=$(git rev-list --max-count=1 $COMMIT $filename)
    echo -e "$node $commit\t$filename"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer from [mas-bagol](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56010861/859485), and for anyone else running into this, the following will include the git commit message:

```sh
# makes for loop works line by line
OIFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'

# assuming $COMMIT is a valid commit-ish
for line in $(git ls-tree $COMMIT)
do
    filename=$(echo $line | cut -f 2)
    # non filename components, tab separated
    node=$(echo $line | cut -f 1 | tr -s ' ' '\t')
    # Output latest entry, with requested fields tab separated
    log_entry=$(git log --format="%H\t%f" -n 1 -- $COMMIT $filename)
    echo -e "$node\t$log_entry\t$filename"
done

IFS=$OIFS
```

This will provide an output where the lines look like:

```
100644  blob    7bfa463a30fd3c5a1e58cdbd64695e0981eea7e0\
    1506412d4638d3a8d0f9e3ee87e55c1a5d0af582    initial commit  README.md
```

The format is:

`<mode> TAB <type> TAB <object> TAB <commit hash> TAB <commit message> TAB <file>`

Tested with git version 2.24.1